# RStudio - missing debugging menu

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am trying to debug my code in RStudio. Here is how it looks with `browser()` function.

[image: screenshot]

It is missing: `Next`, `Continue` and `Stop` buttons as described here: [debug doc](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/debugging-in-r-how-to-easily-and-efficiently-conquer-errors-in-your-code/)

My RStudio version is 1.3.1093 and R version is 4.0.4, I am on Windows 10. How can I get this debug menu?

**Update** I installed Rstudio 2021.09.1 Build 372, but it did not help.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8776     What does running `.rs.haveAdvancedSteppingCommands()` give for you?